# Keras Val_acc is good but prediction for same data is poor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, predict

I am using Keras for a CNN two class classification. While training my val_acc is above 95 percent. But when I predict result for the same validation data the acc is less than 60 percent, is that even possible? This is my Code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1337) # for reproducibility
%matplotlib inline

img_width, img_height = 230,170

train_data_dir = 'data/Train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/Validation'
nb_train_samples =  13044
nb_validation_samples = 200
epochs =14
batch_size = 32

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (1, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 1)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3),data_format='channels_first' , input_shape=(1,230,170))) 
convout1 = Activation('relu')
model.add(convout1)
convout2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2 ), strides= None , padding='valid', data_format='channels_first')
model.add(convout2)

model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3),data_format='channels_first'))
convout3 = Activation('relu')
model.add(convout3)
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_first'))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3),data_format='channels_first'))
convout4 = Activation('relu')
model.add(convout4)
convout5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_first')
model.add(convout5)

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255, 
                                   shear_range=0, 
                                   zoom_range=0.2, 
                                   horizontal_flip=False, 
                                   data_format='channels_first')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255, 
                                  data_format='channels_first')
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    color_mode= "grayscale",
    shuffle=True
)
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    color_mode= "grayscale",
    shuffle=True
)
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    shuffle=True
    )
```

Epoch 37/37

407/407[==============] - 1775s 4s/step - loss: 0.12 - acc: 0.96 - val_loss: 0.02 - val_acc: 0.99

```
#Prediction:
test_data_dir='data/test'
validgen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=False, data_format='channels_first')
test_gen = validgen.flow_from_directory(
         test_data_dir,
         target_size=(img_width, img_height),
         batch_size=1,
         class_mode='binary',
         shuffle=False,
         color_mode= "grayscale")

preds = model.predict_generator(test_gen)
```

In the below output about 7 images belong to class 0. I tried the same for all 100 images of the class 0 validation data and only 15 images were predicted as class 0 and remaining was predicted as class 1

```
Found 10 images belonging to 1 classes.
[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 1.]]
```

Comment: Can you show your code and the output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not scaling your test images by 1./255 as you have in your training and validation images. Ideally, the statistics of your test data should be similar to the training data.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have decided to post the answer I had posted in [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-the-predictions-using-keras-saved-models-are-bad-when-the-training-accuracy-is-97-and-validation-accurcy-is-92-5/answer/Vicente-Murithi) but with the essential part as advised. I too had a similar problem as this one and I hope my answer can help someone else as well. I decided to research on the Internet and came across this [answer by cjbayron](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875#issuecomment-433622588).

What helped me solve a similar issue was that I had the following in my code for training the model:

```
import keras
import os
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import random as rn
import numpy as np

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
np.random.seed(70)
rn.seed(70)
tf.set_random_seed(70)

/******* code for my model ******/

#very important here to save session after completing model.fit 

model.fit_generator(train_batches, steps_per_epoch=4900, validation_data=valid_batches,validation_steps=1225, epochs=40, verbose=2, callbacks=callbacks_list)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = keras.backend.get_session()
saver.save(sess, 'gdrive/My Drive/KerasCNN/model/keras_session/session.ckpt')
```

the saved session will generate the following files as well:

1. /keras_session/checkpoint
2. /keras_session/session.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
3. /keras_session/session.ckpt.index
4. /keras_session/session.ckpt.meta

I downloaded all these files from my Google Drive as well and placed them in a local directory. You might notice that there appears to be no file named *session.ckpt* only but is being used in saver.restore(). This is okay. Tensorflow kinda works it out. It will not bring an error.

**During model.load_model()**

So in my Pycharm, I loaded the model as follows:

```
model=load_model('C:\\Users\\Username\\PycharmProjects\\MyProject\\mymodel\\mymodel.h5')

saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = keras.backend.get_session()
saver.restore(sess,'C:\\Users\\Username\\PycharmProjects\\MyProject\\mymodel\\keras_session\\session.ckpt')

/***** then predict the images as you wish ******/
pred = model.predict_classes(load_image(os.path.join(test_path, file)))
```

It is important to place the restore code as shown i.e. after loading the model.
Once I did this, I tried predicting same images I used for training and validation and this time round, the model wrongly predicted around 2 images per class. Now I was sure that my model was okay and I went ahead to predict with my test images i.e. images it had not seen before and it performed very well.