# Why I have good val_acc during training, but always wrong manul prediction on the same images

Tags: image-processing, keras

I trained my model of CNN net on images with good `val_acc=0.97` and using `model.fit_generator`.

Here is the output of last epoch, proofing high validation accuracy:

```
199/200 [============================>.] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.1563 - acc: 0.9563
200/200 [==============================] - 306s 2s/step - loss: 0.1556 - acc: 0.9565 - val_loss: 0.1402 - val_acc: 0.9691

Epoch 00005: val_acc improved from 0.96701 to 0.96907, saving model to /home/sergorl/cars/color_weights.hdf5
```

But when I use the same validation data set, which I use during training, but test only one image and for every image in my validation set I always get the wrong predicted label and the predicted probabilities looks like a uniform distribution.

I read this links:
[Wrong prediction on images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239431/wrong-prediction-on-images)

[Why is Keras training well but returning wrong predictions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509928/why-is-keras-training-well-but-returning-wrong-predictions)

[Keras Val_acc is good but prediction for same data is poor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112219/keras-val-acc-is-good-but-prediction-for-same-data-is-poor)

But I don't find the solution!

```py
from keras.models import Sequential,Model,load_model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Lambda, Input, Dense, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D, ZeroPadding2D, Dropout, Flatten, merge, Reshape, Activation
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np


class CarColorNet:

    def __init__(self, numClasses=6, imageWidth=256, imageHeight=256):

        self.classes = {}
        self.numClasses = numClasses
        self.imageWidth = imageWidth
        self.imageHeight = imageHeight

        input_image = Input(shape=(self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight, 3))

        # ------------------------------------ TOP BRANCH ------------------------------------
        # first top convolution layer
        top_conv1 = Convolution2D(filters=48, kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(4, 4),
                                  input_shape=(self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight, 3), activation='relu')(input_image)
        top_conv1 = BatchNormalization()(top_conv1)
        top_conv1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(top_conv1)

        # second top convolution layer
        # split feature map by half
        top_top_conv2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, :24])(top_conv1)
        top_bot_conv2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, 24:])(top_conv1)

        top_top_conv2 = Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                      padding='same')(top_top_conv2)
        top_top_conv2 = BatchNormalization()(top_top_conv2)
        top_top_conv2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(top_top_conv2)

        top_bot_conv2 = Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                      padding='same')(top_bot_conv2)
        top_bot_conv2 = BatchNormalization()(top_bot_conv2)
        top_bot_conv2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(top_bot_conv2)

        # third top convolution layer
        # concat 2 feature map
        top_conv3 = Concatenate()([top_top_conv2, top_bot_conv2])
        top_conv3 = Convolution2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                  padding='same')(top_conv3)

        # fourth top convolution layer
        # split feature map by half
        top_top_conv4 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, :96])(top_conv3)
        top_bot_conv4 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, 96:])(top_conv3)

        top_top_conv4 = Convolution2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                      padding='same')(top_top_conv4)
        top_bot_conv4 = Convolution2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                      padding='same')(top_bot_conv4)

        # fifth top convolution layer
        top_top_conv5 = Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                      padding='same')(top_top_conv4)
        top_top_conv5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(top_top_conv5)

        top_bot_conv5 = Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                      padding='same')(top_bot_conv4)
        top_bot_conv5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(top_bot_conv5)

        # ------------------------------------ TOP BOTTOM ------------------------------------
        # first bottom convolution layer
        bottom_conv1 = Convolution2D(filters=48, kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(4, 4),
                                     input_shape=(224, 224, 3), activation='relu')(input_image)
        bottom_conv1 = BatchNormalization()(bottom_conv1)
        bottom_conv1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(bottom_conv1)

        # second bottom convolution layer
        # split feature map by half
        bottom_top_conv2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, :24])(bottom_conv1)
        bottom_bot_conv2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, 24:])(bottom_conv1)

        bottom_top_conv2 = Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                         padding='same')(bottom_top_conv2)
        bottom_top_conv2 = BatchNormalization()(bottom_top_conv2)
        bottom_top_conv2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(bottom_top_conv2)

        bottom_bot_conv2 = Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                         padding='same')(bottom_bot_conv2)
        bottom_bot_conv2 = BatchNormalization()(bottom_bot_conv2)
        bottom_bot_conv2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(bottom_bot_conv2)

        # third bottom convolution layer
        # concat 2 feature map
        bottom_conv3 = Concatenate()([bottom_top_conv2, bottom_bot_conv2])
        bottom_conv3 = Convolution2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                     padding='same')(bottom_conv3)

        # fourth bottom convolution layer
        # split feature map by half
        bottom_top_conv4 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, :96])(bottom_conv3)
        bottom_bot_conv4 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, 96:])(bottom_conv3)

        bottom_top_conv4 = Convolution2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                         padding='same')(bottom_top_conv4)
        bottom_bot_conv4 = Convolution2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                         padding='same')(bottom_bot_conv4)

        # fifth bottom convolution layer
        bottom_top_conv5 = Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                         padding='same')(bottom_top_conv4)
        bottom_top_conv5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(bottom_top_conv5)

        bottom_bot_conv5 = Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',
                                         padding='same')(bottom_bot_conv4)
        bottom_bot_conv5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(bottom_bot_conv5)

        # ---------------------------------- CONCATENATE TOP AND BOTTOM BRANCH ------------------------------------
        conv_output = Concatenate()([top_top_conv5, top_bot_conv5, bottom_top_conv5, bottom_bot_conv5])

        # Flatten
        flatten = Flatten()(conv_output)

        # Fully-connected layer
        FC_1 = Dense(units=4096, activation='relu')(flatten)
        FC_1 = Dropout(0.6)(FC_1)
        FC_2 = Dense(units=4096, activation='relu')(FC_1)
        FC_2 = Dropout(0.6)(FC_2)
        output = Dense(units=self.numClasses, activation='softmax')(FC_2)

        self.model = Model(inputs=input_image, outputs=output)
        sgd = SGD(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
        # sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0005, nesterov=True)
        self.model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    def train(self,
              pathToTrainSet,
              pathToValidSet,
              pathToSaveModel,
              epochs=7,
              batchSize=32,
              stepsPerEpoch=200,
              validationSteps=1000):

        fileOfWeights = 'color_weights.hdf5'
        checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(pathToSaveModel, fileOfWeights),
                                     monitor='val_acc', verbose=1,
                                     save_best_only=True, mode='max')

        checkpoint2 = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(pathToSaveModel, fileOfWeights),
                                     monitor='val_loss', verbose=1,
                                     save_best_only=True, mode='max')

        trainDataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255, shear_range=0.2,
                                          zoom_range=0.3, horizontal_flip=True)

        validDataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)

        trainSet = trainDataGen.flow_from_directory(
                pathToTrainSet,
                target_size=(self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight),
                batch_size=batchSize,
                class_mode='categorical'
        )

        self.classes = {v: k for k, v in trainSet.class_indices.items()}

        np.save(os.path.join(pathToSaveModel, 'class_index.npy'), self.classes)

        validSet = validDataGen.flow_from_directory(
                pathToValidSet,
                target_size=(self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight),
                batch_size=batchSize,
                class_mode='categorical'
        )

        self.model.fit_generator(
            trainSet,
            steps_per_epoch=stepsPerEpoch,
            epochs=epochs,
            validation_data=validSet,
            validation_steps=validationSteps//batchSize,
            callbacks=[checkpoint, checkpoint2])

        print('============================ Saving is here ============================')
        self.model.save(os.path.join(pathToSaveModel, 'car_color_net.h5'))

    @staticmethod
    def load(pathToModel, pathToClassIndexes):

        model = load_model(pathToModel)

        layers = model.layers
        inputShape, outputShape = layers[0].input_shape, layers[-1].output_shape,

        imageWidth, imageHeight = inputShape[1], inputShape[2]
        numClasses = outputShape[1]

        net = CarColorNet(numClasses, imageWidth, imageHeight)
        net.classes = np.load(os.path.join(pathToClassIndexes, 'class_index.npy')).item()

        return net

    def predictOneImage(self, pathToImage):

        frame = cv2.imread(pathToImage)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight))

        frame = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

        # cv2.imshow("boxed", frame[0, :, :, :])
        # cv2.waitKey(0)

        frame = np.asarray(frame, dtype='float32')
        img = frame/255

        probs = self.model.predict(img)
        ind = probs.argmax(axis=-1)[0]

        return self.classes[ind]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pathToTrainSet = '/home/sergorl/cars/train'
    pathToValidSet = '/home/sergorl/cars/valid'
    pathToSaveModel = '/home/sergorl/cars'

    ## Train net
    # net = CarColorNet(numClasses=6)
    # net.train(pathToTrainSet, pathToValidSet, pathToSaveModel)

    # Test on all images from validSet
    net = CarColorNet.load(os.path.join(pathToSaveModel, 'car_color_net.h5'), pathToSaveModel)

    count, countTrueLabels = 0, 0

    for dirpath, _dirnames, filenames in os.walk(pathToValidSet):
        trueLabel = dirpath.split('/')[-1]

        for file in filenames:

            label = net.predictOneImage(os.path.join(dirpath, file))

            print(trueLabel, label)

            if label == trueLabel:
                countTrueLabels += 1

            count += 1

    print('rate is {0:.2f}'.format(float(countTrueLabels) / float(count) * 100))
```

If I have a good `val_acc=0.97`, I'll expect the same result (or nearly), testing every image in validation set. But always have wrong prediction!

I ran net immediately after train was done and see that learning was good:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    pathToTrainSet = '/home/sergorl/cars/train'
    pathToValidSet = '/home/sergorl/cars/valid'
    pathToSaveModel = '/home/sergorl/cars'

    # Train net
    net = CarColorNet(numClasses=6)
    net.train(pathToTrainSet, pathToValidSet, pathToSaveModel)

    # Test on all images from validSet
    count, countTrueLabels = 0, 0

    for dirpath, _dirnames, filenames in os.walk(pathToValidSet):
        trueLabel = dirpath.split('/')[-1]

        for file in filenames:

            label = net.predictOneImage(os.path.join(dirpath, file))

            print(trueLabel, label)

            if label == trueLabel:
                countTrueLabels += 1

            count += 1

    print('rate is {0:.2f}'.format(float(countTrueLabels) / float(count) * 100))
```

So it seems the problem is inside `model.save` and it looks like saving doesn't work!. I found many related issues on git, for example:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4904

But I don't know how to fix it with `Python 3.7.3` and `keras 2.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more about the issue like what is the output you are getting. From the code i can see that you are training for 6 classes and using categorical cross entropy so ideally you should be getting an array with 6 values with each value bw 0 and 1 and the index of highest value in that array should be the output.

Comment: Rohit Thakur, I edited my code above according you requirement

Comment: @Sergey I am still not able to see the output you are getting.

Comment: Rohit Thakur, I added the output from last epoch